# Mongo insert_many Performance - C++

Tags: c++, multithreading, mongodb, mongo-cxx-driver

I am currently trying to **maximize the write speed of insertion** into MongoDB using a C++ application. The behavior that I'm seeing is that the insert_many() operation will slow down, causing the write queue to build up and then subsequent insert_many() operations now have even more to insert. I have made a small sample application to demonstrate the problem. The sample program is defined as two threads:

1. The main thread will read through a dictionary file (one word per line) and count the frequency of each letter in the word and stick each letter's result into a vector and then signal the work thread
2. The worker thread will swap a thread-safe double buffer and then iterate the vector, turning each element into a Document. After iterating the entire vector, we will then do a bulk insert for each letter(collection).

---

```
struct CountData {
    CountData(const size_t p_index, const std::string& p_word, const size_t p_count)
        : index(p_index)
        , word(p_word)
        , count(p_count)
    {
    }

    const size_t index = 0;
    const std::string word;
    const int32_t count = 0;
};

struct CollectionData {
    CollectionData(const std::string& collectionName) : name(collectionName) {
        options.ordered(false);
        auto writeConcern = mongocxx::write_concern{};
        writeConcern.acknowledge_level(mongocxx::write_concern::level::k_unacknowledged);
        options.write_concern(writeConcern);
    }

    void push_back(const bsoncxx::document::value& value) { documents.push_back(value); }
    size_t size() const { return documents.size(); }

    void writeAll(mongocxx::pool& pool) {
        auto client = pool.acquire();
        auto collection = (*client)["frequency"][name];
        collection.insert_many(documents, options);
    }
    void clear() { documents.clear(); }

private:
    const std::string name;
    mongocxx::options::insert options;
    std::vector<bsoncxx::document::value> documents;
};

class FrequencyCounter {
public:
    FrequencyCounter(const std::string& mongoUri, const std::string& dictionaryFile)
        : _collectionNames({ "A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G", "H", "I",
                             "J", "K", "L", "M", "N", "O", "P", "Q", "R",
                             "S", "T", "U", "V", "W", "X", "Y", "Z" })
        , _mongoPool(mongocxx::uri(mongoUri))
        , _dictionary(dictionaryFile)
    {
        for(const auto& name : _collectionNames) {
            _collections.push_back(name);
        }
        _thread = std::thread(&FrequencyCounter::workerThread, this);
    }

    ~FrequencyCounter() {
        _isRunning = false;
        _event.notify_one();
        _thread.join();
    }

    void Run() {
        std::ifstream inFile(_dictionary);
        if(!inFile.is_open()) {
            std::cerr << "Could not open definition file: " << _dictionary << std::endl;
            std::exit(-1);
        }
        std::string line;

        while(std::getline(inFile, line)) {
            std::string word = line;
            std::transform(word.begin(), word.end(), word.begin(), ::toupper);
            size_t index = 0;
            for(const auto& letter : _collectionNames) {
                size_t count = std::count(word.begin(), word.end(), letter[0]);
                if(count > 0)
                    _dataQueue.addPending(CountData(index, word, count));
                ++index;
            }
            _event.notify_one();
        }
    }

private:
    void writeData(const bool flush=false) {
        if(!_dataQueue.trySwap())
            return; // No data to write
        const auto& dataQueue = _dataQueue.active();
        for(const auto& data : dataQueue) {
            const uint64_t begin = DateTime::now();
            auto doc = bsoncxx::builder::basic::document{};
            doc.append(bsoncxx::builder::basic::kvp("word", data.word));
            doc.append(bsoncxx::builder::basic::kvp("count", data.count));
            _collections[data.index].push_back(doc.extract());
            const uint64_t end = DateTime::now();
            _docCreationTimes.emplace_back(end - begin);
        } 

        for(auto& collection : _collections) {
            const size_t currentSize = collection.size();
            if(flush || currentSize >= _maxDocQueueSize) {
                const uint64_t begin = DateTime::now();
                collection.writeAll(_mongoPool);
                const uint64_t end = DateTime::now();
                _docInsertionTimes.emplace_back(end - begin);
                collection.clear();
            }
        }
    }

    void workerThread() {
        try {
            while(_isRunning) {
                _event.wait();
                _event.reset();
                writeData();
            }
            const bool flush = true;
            writeData(flush);
        } catch(const std::exception& ex) {
            std::cerr << "Exception in thread: " << ex.what();
        }
        _isRunning = false;
        {
            uint64_t minTime = std::numeric_limits<uint64_t>::max();
            uint64_t maxTime = 0;
            uint64_t sumTime = 0;
            uint64_t count = 0;
            for(const auto& time : _docCreationTimes) {
                if(time < minTime)
                    minTime = time;
                if(time > maxTime)
                    maxTime = time;
                sumTime += time;
                ++count;
            }
            std::cout << "Doc Creation Time (avg): " << lPadd(std::to_string(sumTime / count), '0', 12) << "ns" << std::endl;
            std::cout << "Doc Creation Time (min): " << lPadd(std::to_string(minTime), '0', 12) << "ns" << std::endl;
            std::cout << "Doc Creation Time (max): " << lPadd(std::to_string(maxTime), '0', 12) << "ns" << std::endl;
        }
        {
            uint64_t minTime = std::numeric_limits<uint64_t>::max();
            uint64_t maxTime = 0;
            uint64_t sumTime = 0;
            uint64_t count = 0;
            for(const auto& time : _docInsertionTimes) {
                if(time < minTime)
                    minTime = time;
                if(time > maxTime)
                    maxTime = time;
                sumTime += time;
                ++count;
            }
            std::cout << "Doc Insertion Time (avg): " << lPadd(std::to_string(sumTime / count), '0', 12) << "ns" << std::endl;
            std::cout << "Doc Insertion Time (min): " << lPadd(std::to_string(minTime), '0', 12) << "ns" << std::endl;
            std::cout << "Doc Insertion Time (max): " << lPadd(std::to_string(maxTime), '0', 12) << "ns" << std::endl;
        }
    }

    const size_t _maxDocQueueSize = 10;
    const std::vector<std::string> _collectionNames;
    mongocxx::instance _mongoInstance;
    mongocxx::pool _mongoPool;
    std::string _dictionary;
    std::vector<CollectionData> _collections;
    AtomicVector<CountData> _dataQueue; // thread-safe double buffer
    std::vector<uint64_t> _docCreationTimes;
    std::vector<uint64_t> _docInsertionTimes;

    Event _event;
    volatile bool _isRunning = true;
    std::thread _thread;
};

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
    const std::string mongoUri = "mongodb://localhost:27017/?minPoolSize=50&maxPoolSize=50";
    const std::string dictionary = "words_alpha.txt";
    FrequencyCounter counter(mongoUri, dictionary);
    counter.Run();

    return 0;
}
```

Results:

```
Doc Creation  Time (avg): 000,000,000,837ns
Doc Creation  Time (min): 000,000,000,556ns
Doc Creation  Time (max): 000,015,521,675ns
Doc Insertion Time (avg): 000,087,038,560ns
Doc Insertion Time (min): 000,000,023,311ns
Doc Insertion Time (max): 005,407,689,435ns
```

I have tried the below alterations with no luck:

- Creating a single Mongo client that remains open during the life of the FrequencyCounter
- Taking from the pool and performing an insert_one() for each item in the vector (both with and without the Pool)
- Using a different Database for each letter and still utilizing the pool and insert_many()

---

Are there any optimizations or changes that I can make that will allow me to have a worker thread that can keep up with the high throughput of the main thread?

Answer (score 0):

I realise this is a relatively old question, but you may see performance improvements using a [collection.bulk_write(bulk_write &bulk_write)](https://mongodb.github.io/mongo-cxx-driver/api/mongocxx-3.0.3/classmongocxx_1_1collection.html#aa1eba9324fa813e24a2608651c8baeff) to insert the records in your worker thread.

These are created by appending a series of operations (`mongocxx::model::insert_one`, `mongocxx::model::delete_one`, etc.) to an instance of `mongocxx::bulk_write`[(class reference docs)](https://mongodb.github.io/mongo-cxx-driver/api/mongocxx-3.0.3/classmongocxx_1_1bulk__write.html) and then executing the batch of prepared operations using `collection.bulk_write(bulk_write)`.

[Some nice examples can be found here](https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-cxx-driver/blob/releases/v3.0/examples/mongocxx/bulk_write.cpp)

---

For comparison of performance,

Test 1:

```
Inserted 100000 in 27263651us insert_one
Inserted 100000 in  1129957us insert_many
Inserted 100000 in   916561us insert_bulk
```

Test 2:

```
Inserted 100000 in 28196463us insert_one
Inserted 100000 in  1089758us insert_many
Inserted 100000 in   967773us insert_bulk
```

---

These figures were obtained using code snippets below (note, mongocxx driver v3.0.3, MongoDB v3.2):

```
struct msg {
    long num;
    long size;
    long time;
}

//using insert_one()
void store_msg_one(std::vector<msg> lst)
{
    for(int i = 0; i < lst.size(); i++)
    {
        msg cur_msg = lst[i];
        bsoncxx::builder::stream::document msg_info_builder{};
        msg_info_builder << "msg_num"   << cur_msg.num
                         << "msg_size"  << cur_msg.size
                         << "msg_time"  << cur_msg.time;        
        bsoncxx::document::value doc_val = msg_info_builder << bson::builder::stream::finalize;

        collection.insert_one(doc_val.view());      
    }
}

//using insert_many()    
void store_msg_many(std::vector<msg> lst)
{
    std::vector<bsoncxx::document::value> lst2; 
    for(int i = 0; i < lst.size(); i++)
    {
        msg cur_msg = lst[i];
        bsoncxx::builder::stream::document msg_info_builder{};
        msg_info_builder << "msg_num"   << cur_msg.num
                         << "msg_size"  << cur_msg.size
                         << "msg_time"  << cur_msg.time;        
        bsoncxx::document::value doc_val = msg_info_builder << bson::builder::stream::finalize;
        lst2.push_back(doc_val);
    }
    collection.insert_many(lst2);
}    

//using bulk_write()
void store_msg_bulk(std::vector<msg> lst)
{
    mongocxx::options::bulk_write bulk_opt;
    mongocxx::write_concern wc;
    bulk_opt.ordered(false); //see https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/bulk-write-operations/
    wc.acknowledge_level(mongocxx::write_concern::level::k_default);
    bulk_opt.write_concern(wc);

    mongocxx::bulk_write bulk = mongocxx::bulk_write{bulk_opt}; 
    for(int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++)
    {
        msg cur_msg = lst[i];
        bsoncxx::builder::stream::document msg_info_builder{};
        msg_info_builder << "msg_num"   << cur_msg.num
                         << "msg_size"  << cur_msg.size
                         << "msg_time"  << cur_msg.time;        

        bsoncxx::document::value doc_val = msg_info_insert << bsoncxx::builder::stream::finalize;
        mongocxx::model::insert_one msg_info_insert_op{doc_val.view()};
        bulk.append(msg_info_insert_op);
    }
    collection.bulk_write(bulk);
}

void main()
{
    std::vector<msg> lst;
    int num_msg = 100000;
    for(int i = 0; i < num_msg; i++)
    {
        msg info;
        info.time = 20*i;
        info.num = i;
        info.size = sizeof(i);
        lst.push_back(info);
    }

    //Test with insert_one(...)
    long long start_microsecs = std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::microseconds>(std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now().time_since_epoch()).count();
    store_msg_one(lst);
    long long end_microsecs = std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::microseconds>(std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now().time_since_epoch()).count();
    std::cout << "Inserted " << num_msg << " in " << end_microsecs - start_microsecs << "us" << " insert_one(...)" << std::endl;

    //Test with insert_many(...)
    start_microsecs = std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::microseconds>(std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now().time_since_epoch()).count();
    store_msg_many(lst);
    end_microsecs = std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::microseconds>(std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now().time_since_epoch()).count();    
    std::cout << "Inserted " << num_msg << " in " << end_microsecs - start_microsecs << "us" << " insert_one(...)" << std::endl;

    //Test with bulk_write(...)
    start_microsecs = std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::microseconds>(std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now().time_since_epoch()).count();
    store_msg_bulk(lst);
    end_microsecs = std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::microseconds>(std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now().time_since_epoch()).count();
    std::cout << "Inserted " << num_msg << " in " << end_microsecs - start_microsecs << "us" << " insert_bulk(...)" << std::endl;         
    std::cin.ignore();
}
```

---

Note: for more information on the bulk_write options, see [MongoDB docs](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/bulk-write-operations/)

EDIT: Formatting